# How to fill column with values based on string contains condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
data = {
    'employee'  : ['Emp1', 'Emp2', 'Emp3', 'Emp4', 'Emp5'],
    'code'      : ['2018_1', '2018_3', '2019_1', '2019_2', '2017_1'],
}

old_salary_bonus = 3000

new_salary_bonus = {
    '2019_1': 1000,
    '2019_2': 980,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Task: Add df['salary_bonus'] column based on the following condition:
If employee's code contains '2019', use code value to retrieve salary bonus value from new_salary_bonus, else use old_salary_bonus value.

Expected Output:

```
   employee  code     salary_bonus
0  Emp1      2018_1   3000
1  Emp2      2018_3   3000
2  Emp3      2019_1   1000
3  Emp4      2019_2   980
4  Emp5      2017_1   3000
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for repplace non matched values:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'employee'  : ['Emp1', 'Emp2', 'Emp3', 'Emp4', 'Emp5'],
    'code'      : ['2018_1', '2018_3', '2019_1', '2019_2', '2017_1'],
}

old_salary_bonus = 3000

new_salary_bonus = {
    '2019_1': 1000,
    '2019_2': 980,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
df['salary_bonus'] = df['code'].map(new_salary_bonus).fillna(old_salary_bonus)
print (df)
  employee    code  salary_bonus
0     Emp1  2018_1        3000.0
1     Emp2  2018_3        3000.0
2     Emp3  2019_1        1000.0
3     Emp4  2019_2         980.0
4     Emp5  2017_1        3000.0
```

Another solution with `get` with default value if not matched:

```
df['salary_bonus'] = df['code'].map(lambda x: new_salary_bonus.get(x, old_salary_bonus))
```

Comment: @KirillChemeritsin I'm very new to python I'm learning things from  SO . while i'm trying to execute your code it is not working can you please post from Import statement to end statement.

Comment: @mohan111 - add `import pandas as pd`

Comment: @jezrael can you please post the entire thing

Comment: @jezrael thanks for posting entire thing now I can run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
df['salary_bonus'] = old_salary_bonus
df.loc[df['code'].isin(list(new_salary_bonus)), 'salary_bonus'] = list(new_salary_bonus.values())
```